# Java :read part of directory files with start index and count

Tags: java, io

for example: there are 1 billion files in a directory,i want to read files and get it's data.but I can not find solution to read part of them ,because 1 billion files are to large and will cause oom ,I want to read part of directory files using like this:

```
FileUtils.getFils("directory path",startIndex,readCount);
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Files#walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) for this:

```
try {
    Files.walk(Paths.get(directoryPath))
            .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile()) // read only files
            .skip(OFFSET)
            .limit(MAX_FILES_PER_ITERATION)
            .forEach(entry -> ... // do you processing here);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // add your exception handling here
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Just add it to a loop and increment  `OFFSET` after every iteration until you reach the 1 billion. I am not sure if it is the optimal way, but give it a try and see how it works.